# How to upload a folder to django database through form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-file-upload

I want to upload a folder containing few files, and save those files to the database. I was successful in uploading a file, but facing problem while trying to upload a folder. The files does not get stored in the database. Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong.

## models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    report_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_diagnoised = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    uploaded_by_doc = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    downloaded_by_rad = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
```

## forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('report_id', 'description', )
```

## views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        uid = request.user.id
        usern = request.user.username
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                for afile in request.FILES.getlist('document'):
                    new_file = Document(document = afile)
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.uploaded_by_doc = usern
                post.document = form.cleaned_data.get('new_file')
                post.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('index')
        else:
            form = DocumentForm()

    return render(request, 'upload.html', context)
```

## upload.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="file" name="document" multiple = "true" webkitdirectory="true" directory = "true"/>
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
```

Comment: you can upload the folder zip if you want to upload a complete folder or i guess you are looking to support multiple file upload?

Comment: its multiple file uploads, but in a folder @SumeetKumar

Comment: multiple file upload in a folder ? what do you mean by this ?

Comment: i mean, i have to upload a folder which contains different types of file @SumeetKumar

Comment: have a look at this [sample code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files) from documentation.